# Use IIS Express with Web Platform Installer?

Tags: iis-7.5, iis-express, web-platform-installer

Is it possible to publish an app on the web pi using iis express (and forcing the installation of it) rather that using straight up IIS?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom feed for Web PI, a hand crafted XML file, that you can load from the Options dialog.

Here is a series of blogs on how to create custom Web PI feeds:

- [Web PI Extensibility: Custom Feeds – Installing Custom Products](http://blogs.iis.net/kateroh/archive/2009/10/24/web-pi-extensibility-custom-feeds-installing-custom-products.aspx)
- [Web PI Extensibility: Custom Feeds – Installing Custom Applications](http://blogs.iis.net/kateroh/archive/2009/10/24/web-pi-extensibility-custom-feeds-installing-custom-applications.aspx)

Here is an example of a product and app that are distributed through a custom feed:

- [Install SIR Web Application with Web PI](http://blogs.iis.net/kateroh/archive/2010/01/25/install-sir-web-application-with-web-pi.aspx)

And here is how you can test whether your feed doesn't have any errors by plugging into Web PI APIs:

- [Web PI APIs: Install a product from a custom feed](http://blogs.iis.net/kateroh/archive/2010/02/11/webpi-apis-install-a-product-from-a-custom-feed.aspx)

Later, in the same dialog, you can choose to have your app installations against IIS Express by selecting:

[image]